# Grocery CRUD search in second page do not include previous pages

Tags: search, grocery-crud

I'm having a problem in Grocery CRUD search.
when i'm in first page, i can search from all the data from the database.
But when i click next and go to the next page, the search function do not include the results from the previous pages...

How can i fix this? is there something that i need to add in my code?

this is my current code in my controller:

```
public function myFunc()
{
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_subject('List');
    $crud->set_theme('twitter-bootstrap');
    $crud->set_table('tbl_list');    
    $output = $crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

Comment: Hello there, the twitter-bootstrap is still in BETA phase. This was not developed by me (I am the author by the way :) ) so I guess changing the theme will help. Try "flexigrid" instead of "twitter-bootstrap"

Comment: but right now i already modified most of the html code of the theme.. i there something that i can add or change in php code that can fix this issue?